# Recursively sending http requests using data from json response

Tags: typescript, node-fetch

I'm trying to extract all names from an API that returns a JSON with the following structure:

```
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "attributes" : {
                "name" : "Prog1"
                ...
            },
            "id" : "12345",
        },
        {
            "attributes" : {
                "name" : "Prog2"
                ...
            },
            "id" : "67890",
        },
        ...
    ],
    "links" : {
        "next" : "https://api.company.com/v1/programs?page%5Bnumber%5D=3",
        "self" : "https://api.company.com/v1/programs?page%5Bnumber%5D=2",
        "prev" : "https://api.company.com/v1/programs?page%5Bnumber%5D=1",
    }
}
```

I want to keep sending requests, and logging the names as long as there is a "next" link, after which I'll stop sending requests.

Here's the function I have so far:

```
async function getPrograms(url: string, user: string, pass: string) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, { 
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${user}:${pass}`).toString('base64')},
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        console.log(response);

        const result = (await response.json()) as GetProgramsResponse;

        result.data.forEach((program) => {
            // Later will add other stuff here
            console.log(program.attributes.name);
        })

        console.log(result.links.next);

        if (result.links.next) {
            getPrograms(result.links.next, user, pass)
        }

    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof Error) {
            console.log('error message: ', error.message);
            return error.message;
        } else {
            console.log('unexpected error: ', error);
            return 'An unexpected error occured';
        }
    }
};

getPrograms(url, u, p);
```

The program hangs after around 6 iterations, not finishing but not continuing either.
I'm assuming it has to do with the requests being sent asynchronously, but I'm relatively new to TypeScript and can't seem to figure out how to wait for all iterations to finish.

Would love for someone to point me to the right direction, and get some feedback regarding the proposed solution as a whole.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to check if the problem lies on the server? You could try checking how long the requests take to return data. You could also use a debugger (or multiple `console.log`) to see where your program hangs.

Comment: You should await `getPrograms(result.links.next, user, pass)`

Comment: TypeScript won't let me add await to it since it's a "top level await"...
I did kind of hack it inside another function and called that function - still no cigar.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR You have missing await ([floating promise](https://mikebifulco.com/posts/eslint-no-floating-promises#what-is-a-floating-promise)) in this part of code:

```
if (result.links.next) {
    await getPrograms(result.links.next, user, pass) // I have awaited this call.
}
```

*If you want to know how async/await is handled in typescript/javascript check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)*

Also I have found some more issues with this snippet.

1. Using recursion to call multiple enpoints isn't the most effiecient way to do that. It only increases call stack size and code complexity. In the worst case scenario, program may won't exit from recursion and it will crash because it's call stack is full.
   I Would suggest using `while` loop (iterate while link.next exists).
2. Instead of using someArray.forEach I suggest using classic for const of loop. It doesn't have any particular performance benefits, but it's easier to read. Also you can call async funtion wthin this loop.

```
for (const program of result.data) {
  await saveToDb(program)
}
```

3. Try to narrow `try/catch` clousre. Having big chunks of code in a singe `try/catch` is a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for the input!
I tried adding await to this line, and it still doesn't finish. I think it did make it somewhat better as now it gets to 10-12 iterations.

Comment: I did also try to implement a while loop, although, it feels very forced in TypeScript as it won't allow me to make a top-level await call to a function... (I'm quite new to TypeScript).
Still doesn't finish and reaches about 12 iterations (There are a total of 19)